# How to connect two applications and hit the API of the first application1 from application2

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services

How can I connect two applications with the scenario below?

**Application1**:
Our infrastructure was created on AWS with `python-django` and `react`, its a private VPC that i can only access via SSH to the EC2 bastion instance (as far as to be able to write codes into)and the way the backend was deployed to create the backend URL `api.mywebsite.com` (which has multiple endpoints) was through `cloudfront` and `Route53`. (`www.mywebsite.com` was built via `s3` and can talk to the backend `api.mywebsite.com`).

**Application2**:
(This is a client infrastructure)
At this time i haven't met the client to know what their system is made of but regardless i need to find a way to write some codes on this system when a specific event is triggered to send data to an API endpoint of **Application1**.

What would be the best way to implement such a logic or API to connect **Application1** and **Application2**?

(Especially considering that **Application1** infrastructure is a private VPC)

This is pretty much the same way that someone would use an API like `STRIPE`...I guess, but i am not sure how to achieve such result...

thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean that api.mywebsite.com was point to Application1?

Comment: @WaketZheng i mean that i want to expose Application1 API endpoint to Application2. Application2 will be able to hit endpoint from Application1

Comment: If the server of Application2 can access the server of Application1 by IP, you can use Nginx to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If understood correctly App1 own by your, App2 is own by 3rd party.

The way I would solve in a scalable way is to deploy a service on  aws lambda that can get requests from App2(or any other app that you would decide in the future) , I would give this service role in order to connect with App1 and would have all logic there.

What you will gain is that your app is secure(you don't expose it to outside 3rd app) , the solution is scalable (you don't need to do nothing if you want to have other apps connecting)

Comment: Interesting, thats the goal indeed because there might be another client that may need that service in the future. the IAM service role that you mentioned above is between services inside the VPC of App1, but how would you consume the logic of App1  from App2 (which is outside the AWS VPC of App1)?

Comment: You dont, you hold the logic inside the service , to APP2 you expose endpoints , you make it secure by closing all incoming  IP's except APP2 IP and adding a code to the request. App2 shouldnt even know that APP1 is even exists